# Unicode supplementary planes in JavaFX

Tags: java, unicode, javafx, javafx-8

I'm having problems dealing with Unicode characters from supplementary ("astral") planes in JavaFX. Specifically, I can't paste such characters in a `TextInputDialog` (I get some weird characters instead, such as `ð`), and can't use them in a WebView (they get rendered as `������`).

The same characters are working perfectly fine if I input them via `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` and print them to the console. They even show in a JavaFX `Alert`, although it appends some junk at the end.

Is there a way to fix these problems?

I'm using Oracle JDK version 1.8.0_51 in Linux.
Examples of supplementary plane characters:     
If you can't see them, you may need to install additional fonts such as Symbola or Noto.

Here's an example program (using a `Label` rather than a `WebView`):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UniTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final String s = new String(new int[]{127137, 178050, 3232, 128512, 241}, 0, 5);
        System.out.println("The string: " + s);
        System.out.println("Characters: " + s.length());
        System.out.println("Code points: " + s.codePoints().count());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, "JOptionPane", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        final Alert al = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        al.setTitle("Alert");
        al.setContentText(s);
        al.showAndWait();

        final TextInputDialog dlg = new TextInputDialog();
        dlg.setTitle("TextInputDialog");
        dlg.setContentText("Try to paste the string in here");
        dlg.showAndWait().ifPresent(x -> System.out.println("Your input: " + x));

        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new Label(s));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        stage.setTitle("Stage");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here are the results I get:

[image: screenshots]

Note: not all the characters in the example are from supplementary planes, and one of the characters is only rendered correctly in the console.

Comment: What are you pasting **from**??? That may make a big difference. From another Java app?

Comment: @Ben From other programs - e.g. a browser or text editor (non-java), also from Eclipse. Pasting in a JOptionPane input dialog works fine, only JavaFX botches the characters.

Comment: @aditsu did you managed to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @JoseRamon not really, but I don't have a great need for this to work right now

Comment: @JoseRamon also, as I mentioned, it's working fine with Swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Evidently JavaFX is buggy.

Here is the text you are using.

```
ಠñ
```

Decimal codepoint representation:

```
127137 178050 3232 128512 241
```

Hex representation:

```
0x1F0A1 0x2B782 0xCA0 0x1F600 0xF1
```

#### Display Bug

Java uses UTF-16 internally. So consider the UTF-16 representation:

UTF-16 representation:

```
D83C DCA1 D86D DF82 0CA0 D83D DE00 00F1
```

We can see that the display is showing the five characters you expect, but then three garbage characters.

So it is clearly trying to display 8 glyphs, where there are only five. This is almost certainly because the display code is counting 8 characters, because three characters are encoded in UTF-16 as surrogate pairs, so take two 16-bit words each. In other words it is using the wrong value for the length of the string in the presence of surrogate pairs.

#### Pasted Text Bug

UTF-8 Representation of test data:

```
F0 9F 82 A1 F0 AB 9E 82 E0 B2 A0 F0 9F 98 80 C3 B1
```

What is seen is

```
00F0 ð LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH 
009F  <control> = APC = APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND 
0082  <control> = BPH = BREAK PERMITTED HERE
00A1 ¡ INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK 
00F0 ð LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH
```

(The two control characters can have glyphs in some fonts containing either their abbreviations or hex codes. These are visible in your example.)

Latin1 hex representation:

```
F0 9F 82 A1 F0
```

Note that these five bytes are the same as the first five bytes of the UTF-8 representation of the intended text.

Conclusion: The pasted data has been pasted as 5 UTF-8 codepoints occupying 17 bytes, but interpreted as 5 Latin1 codepoints occupying 5 bytes. Again, the wrong property has been used for the length.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like that, but didn't work out all the details. I found several OpenJDK bugs related to this problem, such as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8125928 , but they are all marked as resolved... I wonder what's going on.

Comment: It's worse than that Java was designed around UCS-2, not UTF-16. When fixed-length encoding was proved a dead end SUN declared UCS-2 ~ UTF-16 and tried to patch in the differences between them. I bet there are still bugs lurking everywhere in the Java stack, waiting for the unwary to try to use symbols outside the BMP. Other stacks that actually tried to display unicode (not just fill a bullet in a feature list) gave up on UTF-16 early and went UTF-8. That's why people are always hitting conversion problems between the unicode of everyone and the web (UTF-8) and the unicode of Java/windows.

Comment: @JoseRamon Simple: I don't use Java if I can avoid it.

Comment: But what if you cannot avoid it, then what is the solution? Is ridiculous, because some of the characters are working fine and some are not.

Comment: 1) Maybe they've fixed the bug? Are you on the latest version?  
2) My solution is to not use Java, which works for me. I don't have any other solution.
3) Maybe you can intercept the paste event on all text boxes and re-implement it using JNI? And implement your own Alert box?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in Java 10.
See [Java Bug Report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179597).